# How can I inherit a class at project/global level in C#?

Tags: c#, nunit

I need some help with Nunit test classes.

I have written [OneTimeSetUp] and [OneTimeTearDown] methods in a class file and these methods get executed before and after every class correctly.

I have also written [SetUp] and [TearDown] methods in a separate class file to be executed before and after every test case, but these methods do not get executed until I inherit this class in my test class. I have 80 test classes so I will have to inherit it in 80 class files, which I want to avoid.

Comment: sorry, but that's _exactly_ what you will have to do.

Comment: The test framework isn't going to assume that each class should require the logic of your new one - usually different rules apply to different types. So: yeah, I expect you're going to have to add a few `: YourNewType` markers.

Comment: When testing code, emphasis is generally placed on writing test code that is _less likely to break_ rather than _less lines of code_.  For this reason it should be simple/stright-forward.  Don't write unit test code as you would when making an actual system. i.e.  try to avoid unnecessary OO inheritance, interfaces, utility classes, libs etc.  Otherwise _what tests the test code?_   It is not uncommon for unit tests to have a-lot of duplicated code.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses. I will go ahead with this approach.